# C VS Circular dependency? ERROR C2061 - identifier syntax error

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors, dependencies

I'm developing small project in C using Visual Studio.
To avoid multiple includes I'm using include guards.

I'm getting lot of errors including this one:
file: collections.h
error: C2061
description: syntax error: identifier 'Terminal'

synt_analysis.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include "headers\synt_analysis.h"
```

synt_analysis.h

```
#ifndef SYNT_ANALYSIS_H
#define SYNT_ANALYSIS_H

#include "collections.h"

typedef enum {
    ...
}TType;

typedef enum {
    ...
}NTType;

typedef struct {
    TType type;
    ...
}Terminal;

void push_terminal(Terminal terminal, cStack *stack);

#endif
```

collections.h

```
#ifndef COLLECTIONS_H
#define COLLECTIONS_H

#include "synt_analysis.h"

typedef union {
    int error;
    Terminal terminal;
    NTType nttype;
}cItemData;

typedef struct {
    char *type;
    cItemData content;
}cItem;

typedef struct {
    unsigned cap;
    unsigned used;
    cItem *items;
}cStack;

#endif
```

collections provides `cStack`, which can store `Terminal` defined by synt_analysis.
synt_analysis uses `cStack` in function `push_terminal` - which pushes `Terminal` on the Stack. This function exists to reduce amount of code needed (it creates new `Terminal` and pushes it on `cStack`).

Comment: there's no #endif in collections.h

Comment: Forgot it in example, thanks - but it does not solve errors

Comment: Does `#include "synt_anal.h"` include the same file as `#include "headers\synt_analysis.h"`?

Comment: Yep, another mistake in example, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this problem cannot be simply solved by forward declaration (compiler needs to know size of incomplete struct type - it's used as one option of union), the solution is to create another header file, which will break circular dependency.

New file synt_structures.h

```
#ifndef SYNT_STRUCTURES_H
#define SYNT_STRUCTURES_H

#include "lex_analysis.h"

typedef enum {
    ...
}NTType;

typedef enum {
    ...
}TType;

typedef struct {
    TType type;
    ...
}Terminal;

#endif
```

synt_analysis.h includes:

```
#include "collections.h"
#include "synt_structures.h"
```

collections.h includes:

```
#include "synt_structures.h"
```

That breaks the cycle.

Comment: I like this, but what is the `#include "lex_analysis.h"` for?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: The following doesn't actually solve the problem in this case, but I left it here as a useful technique for solving some circular dependencies.

Since `cStack` is only used as part of a pointer type within "synt_analysis.h", it can be an incomplete type within that header file. In order to make it an incomplete type, you need a tag to refer to it.

In "collections.h", add a tag to the `struct` that is used in the definition of the `cStack` type:

```
typedef struct cStack {
    unsigned cap;
    unsigned used;
    cItem *items;
}cStack;
```

In "synt_analysis.h" define the same type as an incomplete type:

```
typedef struct cStack cStack;
```

**EDIT**: As mentioned above, this doesn't actually solve the OP's problem.

Comment: still: 
syntax error: identifier Terminal ---
syntax error: identifier nttype ---
and another 55 errors

Comment: Can you provide a minimally complete example?

Comment: What exactly do you need?
I have tried to put
`typedef struct Terminal Terminal;
typedef enum NTType NTType;
typedef enum TType TType;`
to collections.h and
`typedef struct cStack cStack;`
to synt_analysis.h

And now I have only 1 error:
terminal uses undefined struct Terminal (file collections.h)

Comment: Which `terminal` (with a lower-case 't') gives the error? The `terminal` member of type `cItems` in "collections.h", or the `terminal` parameter of `push_terminal` in "synt_analysis.h", or some other `terminal`? Make sure you use the same struct/union tags consistently on both the complete and incomplete typedefs.

Comment: struct Terminal terminal - from union cItemData in collections.h. I have typedef struct Terminal Terminal; in the beginning of the collections.h file. Maybe it lacks the body of that struct Terminal, so it doesn't know the memory cost of that struct... so I cannot solve circular dependency with forward declaration ?

Comment: Well, I see you managed to solve it. I hope I was of some help, even if I never actually solved your problem!